# NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for hash while using httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I am trying to create content by using api post request and I am using httparty gem.

```
  def initialize(token)
    @token = "Bearer kdkdkfvl"
  end

  def auth
    { AUTHORIZATION: @token }
  end

response = HTTParty.post("url", :headers => { "Authorization" => auth}, :body => article)
```

When I run the code I am getting

`NoMethodError: undefined method`strip' for #
`
I am stuck here. Need some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing in a hash where it's expecting a string.

You want something like:

```
def auth
  @token
end
```

Comment: Or, something along the lines of `HTTParty.post("url", :headers => auth, ...)` (assuming `auth` is in the correct format).